# Unable to perform simple SF cluster upgrade due to NodesToBeRemoved section

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I have a standalone Service Fabric cluster which was been running without issues for a while. I have tried to do a simple cluster upgrade which only updates the ClusterConfigurationVersion, however I am stuck.

My process is the following:

1. Get the current cluster configuration

```
Get-ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration | Out-File clusterconfiguration.json
```

2. Open the clusterconfiguration.json file and update the version before, e.g. from 2.0.0 set to `"ClusterConfigurationVersion": "2.1.0"`
3. Start a new upgrade

```
Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade -ClusterConfigPath .\clusterconfiguration.json
```

This errors out with the following message:

> Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade :
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (-2147017627)
> ValidationException: Model validation error. Nodes have been removed
> from the JSON config but NodesToBeRemoved parameter does not contain
> NodeName for all removed nodes. Please ensure NodesToBeRemoved
> parameter is specified in Setup section inside FabricSettings and node
> names of all nodes which need to be removed from the cluster are
> mentioned.

Upon a closer look I see that there is indeed a NodesToBeRemoved section in my cluster configuration:

```json
{
    "Name": "NodesToBeRemoved",
    "Value": "somenodeX"
}
```

However I don't think I ever intended to remove this node. Also, this node is part of my cluster (although with a different casing, somenodeX vs SomeNodeX). I do not wish to remove this node though.

If I remove the nodes to be removed section then I get this error:

> Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade :
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (-2147017627)
> ValidationException: Model validation error. Nodes have been removed
> from the JSON config but NodesToBeRemoved parameter does not contain
> NodeName for all removed nodes. Please ensure NodesToBeRemoved
> parameter is specified in Setup section inside FabricSettings and node
> names of all nodes which need to be removed from the cluster are
> mentioned.

Do you know how I can un-brick the cluster upgrade process?